# Recuperar via Jquery valor de atributo "data" personalizado

Tags: jquery, json, mvc

Sou iniciante em programação e estou com uma dúvida sobre Jquery (se eu estiver errado, por favor me corrija...rs).

Tenho uma tela que gera várias div's dinamicamente com informações sobre clubes, e dentro de cada div tem um botão que ao clicar, tem que passar 3 parâmetros via JSON ao controller que responde com true ou false a requisição.

O fato é que não consigo de jeito nenhum pegar os parâmetros da div que foi clicada, tenho o seguinte código.

Obs. Os parâmetros que necessito, coloquei em um atributo "data" dentro da tag TD.

Agradeço a ajuda com isso, acredito que seja coisa simples, mas não estou conseguindo mesmo...rsrsrs

```js
< script >
  $(function() {
    $('.ok').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault;
      var IP_Clube = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-ip]').data('ip');
      var Alias_Clube = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-alias]').data('alias');
      var Cod_Clube = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-codigo]').data('codigo');
      $('#divCarregando').modal({
        show: true
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: "/ClubeSlim/Index2",
        contetType: "application/json",
        data: {
          'IP_Clube': IP_Clube,
          'alias_clube': Alias_Clube,
          'cod_clube': Cod_Clube
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
          if (json.ind_statusconexao == true) {
            $('#divCarregando').modal('hide');
            alert('Base do clube ' + Alias_Clube + ' verificado com sucesso!');
            window.location.reload();
          } else {
            $('#divCarregando').modal('hide');
            alert('A conexão com o Clube ' + Alias_Clube + ' FALHOU!');
            window.location.reload();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Clubes)
{
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 style="text-align:center">@item.nom_clube</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td data-codigo="@item.cod_clube">
              <p class="text-muted">Código do Clube: <span class="text-success">@item.cod_clube</span>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p class="text-muted">Empreendimento: <span class="text-success"> @item.nom_empr </span>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p class="text-muted">Capacidade: <span class="text-success"> @item.num_capacidade </span>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-ip="@item.ip_clube">
              <p class="text-muted">IP: <span class="text-success"> @item.ip_clube </span>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-alias="@item.alias_clube">
              <p class="text-muted">Alias: <span class="text-success"> @item.alias_clube </span>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p class="text-muted">Última Atualização: <span class="text-success"> @item.dat_atual </span>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-block ok">Verificar Conexão</button>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <span class="text-info">Última Verificação em : @item.dat_ult_verificacao</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: Onde vem os atributos que você precisa? Ou melhor, como você monta o "data"?

Comment: olá @DiChrist eles são preenchidos no controller com select na tabela e passados via ViewBag para a pagina e na pagina  eu faço um foreach para percorrer a viewbag e montar as divs com as informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar os parâmetro no próprio botão

```
<button data-params='{"IP_Clube":"@item.ip_clube","alias_clube":"@item.alias_clube","cod_clube":"@item.cod_clube"}' class="btn btn-outline btn-success btn-block ok">Verificar Conexão</button>
```

Depois você pode fazer assim:

```
$('.ok').click(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).data("params");
    $.post("/ClubeSlim/Index2", data, function(retorno){
        alert(retorno);
    });
});
```

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que ótimo. Não esquece de marcar a resposta para ajudar outros programadores.

Answer (score 0):

Eu pego os valores dos atributos nomeando eles no HTML na propriedade ID:

```
//JSP
<select name="tipoTk" id="tipoTk" tp="select">

// Script
tipoTk = $("#tipoTk").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  data: {tipoTk: tipoTk},
  ...
```

Comment: olá @Celso Marigo Jr eu tentei dessa forma também, porém ele pega a informação da primeira div gerada, se eu clicar em outra div ele não altera o valor. as divs são geradas depois do foreach percorrer a viewbag com as informações geradas no controller. obrigado